# Presenting view with presentViewController:animated:completion: not working when presentViewController:animated:completion: hotspot enabled

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c

I'm trying to present a view controller modally using presentViewController:animated:completion: (iOS 7) inside viewDidLoad, but when hotspot is enabled it doesn't work. My code looks like this:

```
UINavigationController *navController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"someViewController"];

[self presentViewController:navController animated:NO completion:nil];
```

Does anyone have idea why? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't Present it in viewDidLoad , instead you can load it in **viewDidAppear** method.

```
-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    UINavigationController *navController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"someViewController"];
    [self presentViewController:navController animated:NO completion:nil];
}
```

Just for extra context : You shouldn't call presentViewController in viewDidLoad because the controller isn't visible yet (possibly not even in the controller hierarchy, but I'm not sure), and thus is not able to present another controller. - @hukir.

Comment: Just for extra context, you shouldn't call presentViewController in viewDidLoad because the controller isn't visible yet (possibly not even in the controller hierarchy, but I'm not sure), and thus is not able to present another controller.

Comment: yeah, you're right, i ended up using viewWillAppear, since i needed to present the view without animation, and doing it in viewDidAppear, the "parent" view is shown for like a millisecond.

Comment: Also, if anyone find this helpful, i needed to use a BOOL to know whether the view controller was already presented or not. Thanks, i will accept your answer @Viruss

Comment: @GabrielHernández, are you sure you successfully presented a viewcontroller in `viewWillAppear`? Normally, you should be getting 'Attempt to present x on x whose view is not in the window hierarchy' if you did that, at least on iOS 7.x and 8.x.